# Uploadify not working with jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, uploadify, jquery-ui-tabs

So here's deal... I'm having 2 jQuery UI tabs - 1st is General Info and 2nd is Gallery. On the 2nd tab I have an uploadify button with multiple upload option enabled. When I stack several images in the queue for uploading and click upload they start uploading one by one (so this is fine...), but if I click on the first tab while the process is going, Uploadify stops working and no longer processes the queue, it just stops uploading, the queue stays and won't continue, no errors thrown as well.

Any ideas why? Has anybody noticed something like that before?

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1, my jQuery UI is v1.8.2 and Uploadify is v2.1.0.

**Update:** Here is a piece of the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : '/flash/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'ajaxUploadImage.php',
        'cancelImg'      : '/images/icons/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : '',
        'auto'           : false,
        'multi'          : true,
        'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'fileDesc'       : 'Image files',
        'fileDataName'   : 'image_gallery',
        'sizeLimit'      : 10485760,
        onComplete: function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data){
            // do stuff
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-main"><span>Main Info</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-gallery"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-main">
        <!-- some stuff here not related to the problem -->
    </div>

    <div id="tab-gallery">
        <input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />
        <div id="uploadify-queue-btns">
            <button type="button" id="uploadify-start-upload"onclick="javascript:$('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();"> Upload</button>
            <button type="button" id="uploadify-clear-queue" onclick="javascript:$('#uploadify').uploadifyClearQueue();"> Clear queue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the tabs filled? Properly the JS events are going lost when the uploadify JS is manually pushed into the tabs div.

Comment: Hi @powtac. I just uploaded some of the code that I'm using, you can take a look at it. Yes I'm pushing the uploadify manually to start the process. I may try using the auto option and see if this will fix it.

Comment: Just tried using auto:true, but it's the same. No effect. Any suggestions? Anyone?

Comment: Yes I do. I tried this with firebug on and off. Otherwise no errors in firebug.

Comment: Yes... of course it does, I don't see why it won't work without ui-tabs. I need it inside jquery ui tabs though and the question is why it's not working properly inside jquery ui tabs.